# getting error NullPointerException in Java

Tags: java

i am getting error Java.lang.NullPointerException..i am beginner in java please help on this.....i am running this code in Netbeans

```
if ((cmbDate.getSelectedItem().equals("")) &&  (cmbMonth.getSelectedItem().equals("")) && (cmbYear.getSelectedItem().equals(""))) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Please select DOB","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           return;
            }
```

Comment: Do you know what `NullPointerException` means? (Have you Googled it?) If so, then -- do you know which reference is null? (Have you tried adding debugging statements, or using a debugger?)

Comment: Check what's the return value of cmbDate.getSelectedItem(), cmbMonth.getSelectedItem() and cmbYear.getSelectedItem(). Usually, null pointer exception is thrown when you are invoking a method on a variable which value is null. This is probably the most common error in Java... so feel free to Google it and learn a little bit.

Comment: Provide stack trace of the NPE in your question.

Answer (score 1):

when you have a static content and a dynamic variable to test against using eqauls, always use the static part in the left like

```
"".equals(cmbDate.getSelectedItem())
```

it will rescue from cases where `cmbDate.getSelectedItem()` is null.

Also assuming the objects also can be null

```
if ((cmbDate == null || "".equals(cmbDate.getSelectedItem())) ||  (cmbMonth ==null || "".equals(cmbMonth.getSelectedItem())) || (cmbYear ==null ||"".equals(cmbYear.getSelectedItem()))) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Please select DOB","Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is great advice. If `cmbDate.getSelectedItem()` is null, that probably means either that there's a bug (in which case your suggestion will mask the bug), or else that it should be treated as the empty string (in which case your suggestion will give the wrong result).

Comment: its not working..........its not checking for null string

Comment: @RajSharma check the update, you were suppose to check `OR` not `AND`

Comment: @ruakh in that what would the preferred way to check for the null value? using an assertion? because logically it should not be null - like `assert cmbDate.getSelectedItem() != null`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: If it's never supposed to happen that `cmbDate.getSelectedItem()` is null, then I don't see much point in explicitly checking for it: just let the `NullPointerException` happen. (If you do want to check for it explicitly, e.g. to give a more informative error message, then I'd suggest writing something like `if (cmbDate.getSelectedItem() == null) throw new NullPointerException("cmbDate.getSelectedItem()")`.)

Comment: @ruakh an assertion also does the same right

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Assertions may or may not run (depending on runtime configuration), so adding `assert cmbDate.getSelectedItem() != null` means that, when the bug is triggered, the code will throw *either* `AssertionError` *or* `NullPointerException`. I don't see much benefit to introducing that ambiguity; why not just always throw the same thing? (I'd be more supportive of something like `if (cmbDate.getSelectedItem() == null) throw new AssertionError("cmbDate.getSelectedItem() == null")`, which behaves consistently.) But that's just my opinion, of course; you're welcome to disagree.

Comment: 1st thing u guys are not able to solve my this problem and rating my question not useful...its really shame yar...i am a new user and u guys wont get anything to decrease my reputation...

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure any of this controls return null item and verify the control itself.

```
 cmbDate.getSelectedItem() 
 cmbYear.getSelectedItem()
 cmbYear.getSelectedItem()
```

And change the code like below. If you got any null we are verified but your desire ouput will vary.

```
     if ((cmbDate.getSelectedItem() !=null && cmbDate.getSelectedItem().equals(""))                       
              &&  (cmbMonth.getSelectedItem() !=null &&cmbMonth.getSelectedItem().equals(""))
          && (cmbYear.getSelectedItem() !=null && cmbYear.getSelectedItem().equals(""))) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( this, "Please select DOB","Error",    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
             return;
       }
```

Comment: its not working..............

Answer (score 0):

1. cmbDate
2. cmbMonth
3. cmbYear

Either of the above can be null. You need to check if they are null before performing operations on them.